# How do I uninstall an app?

Tags: software-installation

I found another thread about this and it was suggested that "go to the aplications menu (at the left of the top of your screen) and look for software center, from there you can install and uninstall a lot of things with just a click"

But I don't have software center in my applications!?

Answer (score 1):

In elementary OS 0.4 loki it is called *AppCenter*. Under the *Updates* tab you can look at the list of the apps installed and uninstall those you want to.

There are some applications you can only install/remove with the command line. To list/remove them you can use the command line tool `apt`:

```
user@host:~$ apt-cache search keepass
keepass2 - Password manager
keepass2-doc - Password manager - Documentation
keepassx - Cross Platform Password Manager
kpcli - command line interface to KeePassX password manager databases
libfile-keepass-perl - interface to KeePass V1 and V2 database files

user@host:~$ apt remove keepass2
```

Comment: I see. Well I had a look and for instance I wanted to uninstall keepass and it's not listed there. Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't it keepass2 or keepassx ?

Comment: it is keepass2 but it happened with libre office too